# How to create a LinearLayout inside class that extend Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, android-linearlayout

Does anyone know how to create LinearLayout in Fragment?
I would like to display TextView, ListView in a layout, so I would like to create it in a LinearLayout.
However, I cannot create the LinearLayout in the class like: `LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);`

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

    return rootView;


}}
```

This is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff8400" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Design Games Screen"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: Why can't you create your linear layout in the xml file itself instead of doing it programatically?

Comment: Because I'm not really familiar with XML, is there any way to create it in java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a LinearLayout inside your fragment's layout file. If there is no reason to create it programatically, then use the xml file like this:

```
 <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#ff8400" >

     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Games Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
     <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

That way, when you inflate the layout in your fragment, you will have the linear layout in it already defined. I hope this helped.

Comment: Why, oh why, did you keep the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Is there anyway to create in java code? @Eenvincible

Comment: Sure. You can just do LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity); then add to the root element

Comment: May I know how to add into root?

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137 updated link with better example